# Using Excel, How to split a number randomly to different cells but still total up to the original value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take the total number (the highlighted numbers) per each column  and split it randomly in the cells of the same column, till the end.
[image]

Every country will have a random number. All the random numbers for each country have to sum up to the total number.

Pageviews nr > Impressions nr > Clicks nr

C > D > E

The number in column C has to be bigger than D.
The number in column D has to be bigger than E.

Comment: C D E columns are the most important ones.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written - Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Also, what about uniformity? Picking a random number isn't hard but equality amongst them would be somewhat harder to preserve.

Comment: Hint: you can use `RANDBETWEEN` function to set up individual country data and then use `SUM` formula to get totals at the top. Post your attempt as Applecore has pointed out.

Comment: This could be done with th Solver.

Comment: How can you have C>D, if the sum in D is ~300% greater than the sum in C?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry you're right, that one should be the opposite. My mistake.

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, Microsoft 365 has been configured to prevent individual acquisition of Office Add-ins. :/

Comment: Solver is available for 365 - I have the latest version and use it every day.

Comment: @SolarMike but I don't have administrator permissions to configure the Office Add-ins

Comment: @Applecore 
Sub test()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("C4:C102").Formula = "=Rand()"


End Sub

This gives me random numbers but I don't know how to condition the random values to add up to my total number

Comment: You don’t need admin access - it is a user level install as part of excel.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for ideas, here's one:

Starting with the column of the minimum sum (column E)

- Split your sum **evenly** in an array of n elements (n = number of rows of destination range)
- select 2 random indexes say i1 and i2. Take a random amount from element i1 and add it element i2. Repeat this for (say) n * 3 times.

For the next column (D) do the same thing, but instead of randamising the sum of that column, randomise the **difference** (i.e. D2-E2). Once you have a random distribution of this sum difference, you can simply add it to values of the previous column (E).

Repeat for the following column (C) by randmising the difference in sum (C2-D2).

I hope I managed to convey the idea clearly.

**Edit 1**: following your comment.

**Example**

To split 100 into a sum of 5 random numbers:

1. Split the sum into an array of 5 numbers evenly. **Result1**: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
2. Choose 2 random indexes say 1 and 3. Determine a random amount, say 4. Subtract 4 from element 1 and add it to element 3. **Result2**: [16, 20, 24, 20, 20]
3. Choose 2 random indexes say 4 and 2. Determine a random amount, say 15. Subtract 15 from element 4 and add it to element 2. **Result3**: [16, 35, 24, 5, 20]
4. Choose 2 random indexes say 5 and 1. Determine a random amount, say 9. Subtract 9 from element 5 and add it to element 1. **Result4**: [25, 35, 24, 5, 11]

Now we want to split 235 into a sum of 5 random numbers making sure that each element is greater than the corresponding element in **Result4**

1. To start I am going to split 135 (i.e. the difference 235-100) into a sum of 5 random numbers.
2. Using the same steps above (for splitting 100) we end up with **Result5**: [40, 55, 9, 14, 17]
3. Finally to get the sum of 235, we add corresponding elements of **Result4** and **Result5** [25+40, 35+55, 24+9, 5+14, 11+17] to get **Result6**: [65, 90, 33, 19, 28]

Therefore, we managed to split **100** into **(25+35+24+5+11)** and **235** into **(65+90+33+19+28)**.

I hope I haven't made any arithmetic error.

**Edit 2**: Implementation as a UDF that returns an array

```
Function SplitSum(SumToSplit As Double, _
                  N As Long, _
                  Optional MinAmount As Double = 0, _
                  Optional RoundToNearest As Double = 1) As Variant
    
    '* Parameters:
    '
    '  SumToSplit:       The sum to split
    '
    '  N:                The number of elements to split the sum into
    '
    '  [MinAmount]:      The minimum amount any element can have.
    '                    Default value is 0 -> all elements are positive
    '
    '  [RoundToNearest]: Each element will be rounded to the nearest RoundToNearest.
    '                    Default value is 1 -> all elements rounded to the nearest integer
    '                    To round elements to 2 decimal places set RoundToNearest=0.01
    '                    To round elements to the nearest 50 cents, set RoundToNearest=0.5
    '                    To round elements to the nearest 0.1%, set RoundToNearest=0.001
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dExchangeAmount As Double
    Dim lFrom As Long, lTo As Long
    Dim dSum As Double: dSum = 0
    Dim arrRandomVals() As Double: ReDim arrRandomVals(1 To N, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Split the sum evenly first
    arrRandomVals(1, 1) = SumToSplit / N
    For i = 2 To N
        arrRandomVals(i, 1) = arrRandomVals(i - 1, 1)
    Next i
    
    Randomize Now
    For i = 1 To N * 5
        lFrom = Int(Rnd * N) + 1
        lTo = Int(Rnd * N) + 1
        dExchangeAmount = Rnd * arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1)
        If lFrom <> lTo And arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) - dExchangeAmount >= MinAmount Then
            arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) = arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) - dExchangeAmount
            arrRandomVals(lTo, 1) = arrRandomVals(lTo, 1) + dExchangeAmount
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Apply rounding
    For i = 1 To N - 1
        arrRandomVals(i, 1) = Round(arrRandomVals(i, 1) / RoundToNearest, 0) * RoundToNearest
        dSum = dSum + arrRandomVals(i, 1)
    Next i
    arrRandomVals(N, 1) = SumToSplit - dSum
    
    SplitSum = arrRandomVals
End Function
```

**Update:**

After using this function myself, I came across a few issues that are fixed below:

```
Function SplitSum(SumToSplit As Double, _
                  N As Long, _
                  Optional MinAmount As Double = 0, _
                  Optional RoundToNearest As Double = 1) As Variant
    
    '* Parameters:
    '
    '  SumToSplit:       The sum to split
    '
    '  N:                The number of elements to split the sum into
    '
    '  [MinAmount]:      The minimum amount any element can have.
    '                    Default value is 0 -> all elements are positive
    '
    '  [RoundToNearest]: Each element will be rounded to the nearest RoundToNearest.
    '                    Default value is 1 -> all elements rounded to the nearest integer
    '                    To round elements to 2 decimal places set RoundToNearest=0.01
    '                    To round elements to the nearest 50 cents, set RoundToNearest=0.5
    '                    To round elements to the nearest 0.1%, set RoundToNearest=0.001
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    ' First deal with situations that don't make sense
    If Round(Round(MinAmount / RoundToNearest, 0) * RoundToNearest, 10) <> Round(MinAmount, 10) Or _
       Round(Round(SumToSplit / RoundToNearest, 0) * RoundToNearest, 10) <> Round(SumToSplit, 10) Then
       SplitSum = "#'SumToSplit' & 'MinAmount' must be rounded to 'RoundToNearest'"
       Exit Function
    End If
    If MinAmount * N > SumToSplit Then
        SplitSum = "#'MinAmount' " & Chr(215) & " 'N' must be less than or equal to 'SumToSplit'" ' CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dExchangeAmount As Double
    Dim lFrom As Long, lTo As Long
    Dim dSum As Double: dSum = 0
    Dim arrRandomVals() As Double: ReDim arrRandomVals(1 To N, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Split the sum evenly first
    arrRandomVals(1, 1) = SumToSplit / N
    For i = 2 To N
        arrRandomVals(i, 1) = arrRandomVals(i - 1, 1)
    Next i
    
    Randomize Now
    For i = 1 To N * 25
        lFrom = Int(Rnd * N) + 1
        lTo = Int(Rnd * N) + 1
        dExchangeAmount = Rnd * arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1)
        If lFrom <> lTo And arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) - dExchangeAmount >= MinAmount Then
            arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) = arrRandomVals(lFrom, 1) - dExchangeAmount
            arrRandomVals(lTo, 1) = arrRandomVals(lTo, 1) + dExchangeAmount
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Apply rounding
    For i = 1 To N - 1
        arrRandomVals(i, 1) = Round(arrRandomVals(i, 1) / RoundToNearest, 0) * RoundToNearest
        dSum = dSum + arrRandomVals(i, 1)
    Next i
    arrRandomVals(N, 1) = SumToSplit - dSum
    
    ' Sometimes the last element goes below MinAmount
    If arrRandomVals(N, 1) < MinAmount Then
        For i = 1 To N - 1
            If arrRandomVals(i, 1) + (MinAmount + arrRandomVals(N, 1)) > MinAmount Then
                arrRandomVals(i, 1) = arrRandomVals(i, 1) + (MinAmount + arrRandomVals(N, 1))
                arrRandomVals(N, 1) = MinAmount
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    SplitSum = arrRandomVals
End Function
```

Comment: I fail to see how that helps me solve my problem.  What I want to achieve is to Split the SUM=89839 randomly in 99 rows. Randomly

Comment: Well, using the steps above, I managed to split the 1813 into (11+13+106+127+53+12+86+101+25+11+213+13+41+68+46+12+11+96+68+28+12+32+14+14+75+11+14+54+154+57+32+26+151+14+12) [35 values, but easily adaptable to 99 values]. Try to read it again and if there's anything that doesn't make sense don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You deserve a medal my friend. It all makes sense now :)
Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Ok, since you gave me a medal, I updated my answer with my implentation. It's a user defined function that returns and array. To use it you should be comfortable with array formulae. If not, just google "array formulas in excel"

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it a lot :) . I had so much fun yesterday trying to figure it out btw. I came up with a way but that was longer cuz I'm not the best in math (lol) . And then I saw your answer which made everything clearer :). Again thank you. I love communities like Stackoverflow, because of people like you :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
Sub RandomiseSum()
    Dim countries As Range, country As Range
    Dim arr() As Double, i As Integer
    
    Set countries = Range("A3:A17")  '~~> update as per actual data
    ReDim arr(countries.Count - 1)
    
    For i = 0 To countries.Count - 1
        arr(i) = Rnd
    Next i
    
    arrayCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr)
    
    For Each country In countries
        country.Offset(0, 2) = arr(country.Row - 3) / arrayCount * Range("C2")
        country.Offset(0, 3) = arr(country.Row - 3) / arrayCount * Range("D2")
        country.Offset(0, 4) = arr(country.Row - 3) / arrayCount * Range("E2")
    Next country
End Sub
```

*Notes*

1. First create an array of random numbers between 0 and 1. (using `Rnd`). The length of the array is the same as the number of countries
2. Sum the array.
3. Loop over each country and calculate a random number of clicks, impressions etc.
4. By dividing the array value by the total array sum we effectively ensure that the random numbers all sum to 1. This means that when you add your numbers up in each column they will total to the numbers you have in row 2.